# SWT Nebula gantt chart component

Tags: java, swt, nebula

I am trying to use Nebulla Gantchart component for a project. We need a standard project management like view, with a table beside the gantt chart. Unfortunately it is not easy to align the rows of a Grid and gantt chart component at all. 
There is a sample, which tries to do this with a tree component. But it is not precise. the row height are a little different between chart and tree, beside, scrolling messes things up completely.

Does anybody have a solution for this please?

Answer (score 0):

This might come a little late, but here are some hints based on my experience working with Nebula's Gantt chart.

**Regarding the row hight issue between the tree and chart.** Gantt charts may be created with custom settings by passing in your own class in the GanttChart constructor. Nebula recommends extending nebula.widgets.ganttchart.AbstractSettings when creating this class. A few methods you may want to look at and/or override:

```
AbstractSettings.getEventsTopSpacer()
AbstractSettings.getEventsBottomSpacer()
AbstractSettings.getSectionBarDividerHeight()
AbstractSettings.getSectionBarWidth()
```

You may also want to to look at AbstractSettings.lockHeaderOnVerticalScroll() - I needed to lock the header bar then add padding above my table to get the alignment correct.

**Regarding linking the tree/chart during scrolling.** It is possible to add an SWT.Selection listener to the vertical bar on your tree. Then, when the tree scrolls, you can force the gantt to scroll as well. For me, this looked something like:

```
treeViewer.getTree().getVerticalBar().addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener(){
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event){
        TreeItem ti = treeViewer.getTree.getTopItem();
        ganttChart.getGanttComposite().setTopItem((GanttEvent) ti.getData(), 6, SWT.LEFT);
    }
});
```

Note that this does not work very well the other way around; if you try to link the scroll action of the gantt chart to the tree, the response will not be as snappy. This is due to how gantt charts scroll smoothly, rather than element-by-element, like a tree. I circumvented this issue by disabling the scroll bar on the Gantt, but that is a less-than-desirable fix.

In addition to this, I had to add an SWT.Resize listener to align the tree/chart whenever the viewer was resized.

Hopefully this is points you in the right direction! Good luck.